# How to check if a wired connection is present in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm running the following batch file when logging in:

```
::if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit

:: See if NAS is connected locally
Dir \\192.168.0.26\Docker\CheckFile.txt
If %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 GoTo FileSpecifiedIsHere
GoTo ItIsntHere
Pause This line is never reached

:FileSpecifiedIsHere
::Do whatever I want to if the one specified is detected
Start "Starting the application" /MIN "C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Synapse3\WPFUI\Framework\Razer Synapse 3 Host\Razer Synapse 3.exe
GoTo EndThisBatch

:ItIsntHere
::Do whatever I want to if the one specified is not detected
Start "Starting the application" /MIN "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUSTOR\EZ Connect\EasyConnect.exe"
GoTo EndThisBatch

:EndThisBatch
```

This worked as intended on my previous laptop, but it always seems to jump to 'ItIsntHere' when run at login on this laptop. If I run the batch file manually it's working as intended, it just isn't working properly at login. I've tried added delays and that hasn't made a difference.

I think the next step would be instead of checking for my NAS, checking if an ethernet connection is present or not - how would I set up a check for this?

Cheers

Comment: I am certain that questions whereby a requirement to determine if a wired, and/or wireless network connection has been established, have been asked before. Please use the search facility at the top of the page to locate and adapt some code for your needs. We are not here to give you, or tell you how to, code, moreso to help you to fix a problem with your own. As for your code, I'm not sure why you'd use `Dir` over `If Exist`, or why you wouldn't use ```PushD "\\192.168.0.26\Docker" 2>NUL || GoTo EndThisBatch``` first, then ```If Exist "CheckFile.txt" (PopD) Else PopD & GoTo ItIsntHere)```.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I felt like I did a pretty thorough search before creating the thread - if there are any specific posts you had in mind, please do link me.

I tried your suggestions, but the code failed, even when just switching 'Dir' to 'If Exist' it didn't work.
Also, to clarify, I'd want 'PushD "\\192.168.0.26\Docker" 2>NUL || GoTo EndThisBatch' to go to 'ItIsntHere' instead so I can launch the relevant program, and then 'If Exist "CheckFile.txt" (PopD) Else PopD & GoTo ItIsntHere)' to go to 'FileSpecifiedIsHere' instead so again, I can launch the relevant program.